# Getting the parameters of form-base authentication Tomcat (j_security_check) to initialize a User object

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I'm working with tomcat 7, Java EE6. I'm using form-base authentication and all working fine. But I would like to use the parameters of the form `j_security_check`, these are the `j_username` and `j_password`, in order to use them to initialize a User object.

I haven't find information regarding it, so what I´m doing is to make the user to register two times, once to enter the protected area with form-base authentication (tomcat 7) and a second time to get the same parameters (`j_username` and `j_password` ) and initializing the user object, but I'm wondering if this second step could be avoided. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getRemoteUser()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser()) to recover the username that was used to authenticate.

You can then use this to lookup the password (hopefully one-way hashed) in whatever user registry it is that you have configured in Tomcat.